# receiving "None" as result in CVXPY problem solver

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

Trying to solve TSP as linear programming task using cvxpy and have problem with this. It is my first experience so thanks for help. As a result I want to have matrix with 0 and 1 that shows every next city for salesman.

need to use exactly cvxpy

[here you can read theory](http://github.com/cochoa0x1/integer-programming-with-python/blob/master/05-routes-and-schedules/traveling_salesman.ipynbhttps://)

[cvxpy website](https://cvxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

thanks for help

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
N = 10
distances = np.random.rand(N, N)  

x = cp.Variable((N, N), boolean=True)
u = cp.Variable(N, integer=True)

constraints = []

for j in range(N):                                      
    indices = list(range(0, j)) + list(range(j + 1, N))
    constraints.append(cp.sum(x[indices, j]) == 1)
for i in range(N):
    indices = list(range(0, i)) + list(range(i + 1, N)) 
    constraints.append(cp.sum(x[i, indices]) == 1)
for i in range(1, N):                      
    for j in range(1, N):
        if i != j:
            constraints.append(u[i] - u[j] + N*x[i, j] <= N-1)

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if i != j:
            сost += (x[i,j]*distances[i,j]) 

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost), constraints)
prob.solve()
print(prob.value)
```

receive "None"

feel like the problem in cost defining, but don`t know how to make it correct 
maybe I should use cvxpy.multiply or cvxpy.sum?

Comment: (1) print `prob.status` (2) add `verbose=True` to the solve statement (3) make sure the code in the question is self-contained so we could have executed this code.

Comment: returns "infeasible_inaccurate".
don't understand what I am doing incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know what was the problem. maybe smth with Jupyter. everything became ok after it refreshing 
thanks all for help!

Answer (score 0):

The default MIP-solver coming with cvxpy is just a proof of concept and very unstable in non-tiny instances. Things like that happen then and there is not much you can do.

Like Erwin asked for in aboves comment: activate `verbose=True` and you might recognize the solver in use. I'm guessing: `ECOS_BB`. It's the only one available in the default install.

The situation in regards to deploying a MIP solver which:

- is easily installed on windows
- is of high-quality
- is open-source

is not great.

The easiest approach of obtaining a usable one on windows is using pre-built [glpk](https://www.cvxpy.org/install/#install-with-cvxopt-and-glpk-support) through cvxopt.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not the problem here, be sure to call `prob.solve()`. Otherwise, prob.value is None